# Single invocation at a time

Tags: function, go, concurrency

I want to call function for each of several inputs in parallel.
How is it possible to organize goroutines communication if there is a restriction: one function's call at a time?

Comment: It looks that you will get no benefit from concurrency in this case. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Use a [mutex](https://godoc.org/sync#Mutex) to limit execution to one goroutine a time.

Comment: @CeriseLimón, I can't modify my function, so I have to wrap it with another function with mutex object included. Am I right?

Comment: @GrzegorzŻur, yes, you are right - I will not receive any benefit from concurrency at this stage. I have to build up a pipeline with this function as a one stage of it.